# Open MPI Hangs over multiple hosts

Tags: cluster-computing, mpi, redhat, freeze, openmpi

So I've been trying to get openmpi to work over two hosts, and whenever I type out my command it just hangs.  Using the debug I managed to see that the native server successfully executed mpi after the /tmp command, however host2 hangs there.

> $ mpirun --prefix /usr/lib/openmpi -d -host server10 hello
>
> [server9:09833] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-jonesi1@server9_0/58918/0/0
>
> [server9:09833] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-jonesi1@server9_0/58918/0
>
> [server9:09833] top: openmpi-sessions-jonesi1@server9_0
>
> [server9:09833] tmp: /tmp
>
> [server9:09833] mpirun: reset PATH: /usr/lib/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:/home/[my username]/bin
>
> [server9:09833] mpirun: reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/openmpi/lib:/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib
>
> [server10:01982] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-jonesi1@server10_0/58918/0/1
>
> [server10:01982] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-jonesi1@server10_0/58918/0
>
> [server10:01982] top: openmpi-sessions-jonesi1@server10_0
>
> [server10:01982] tmp: /tmp

I've seen a lot of people suggesting ssh might be blocked, however the command ssh server10 mpirun hello works fine.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to proceed?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the firewall on the two machines is off. On Linux, you can do it with

```
iptables -L
```

SSH might work as the firewall will allow it, but MPI will need a different (high) port that could be blocked off.